# Is there a PlayStation version of Starcraft?

Tags: starcraft

This SMBC Theater [video](http://www.smbc-theater.com/?id=264) seems to imply that there is a PlayStation version of StarCraft. Is there?

Comment: I think the reason they used a playstation controller for that is that it seems be a more "typical" controller - I find a lot of media will use that basic shape when they use controllers for an unnamed (i.e. non-existent) console in their media.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no Playstation version of Starcraft, though there is a Nintendo 64 one.

According to Wikipedia:

> In 2000, StarCraft 64 was released for
>   the Nintendo 64, co-developed by
>   Blizzard Entertainment and Mass Media
>   Inc. The game featured all of the
>   missions from both StarCraft and the
>   expansion Brood War, as well as some
>   exclusive missions, such as two
>   different tutorials and a new secret
>   mission, Resurrection IV. Resurrection
>   IV is set after the conclusion of
>   Brood War, and follows Jim Raynor
>   embarking on a mission to rescue the
>   Brood War character Alexei Stukov, a
>   vice admiral from Earth who has been
>   captured by the Zerg. The Brood War
>   missions required the use of a
>   Nintendo 64 memory Expansion Pak to
>   run. In addition, StarCraft 64
>   features a split screen cooperative
>   mode, allowing two players to control
>   one force in-game. StarCraft 64 was
>   not as popular as the PC version, and
>   lacked the online multiplayer
>   capabilities and speech in mission
>   briefings. In addition, cut scenes
>   were shortened. **Blizzard Entertainment
>   had previously considered a
>   PlayStation port of the game, but it
>   was decided that the game would
>   instead be released on the Nintendo
>   64.**

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarCraft#Nintendo_64_version)